# SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider returns only aspnetdb users - WHY?

Tags: 2010, development, authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

If I use :

```
MembershipProvider membership = Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"];
MembershipUserCollection msc = membership.GetAllUsers(0, 200000, out totalnumber);
```

I got all userS from asnpnet db. That is ok.

If I use:

```
MembershipProvider membership = Membership.Providers["i"];
MembershipUserCollection msc = membership.GetAllUsers(0, 200000, out totalnumber);
```

Again, I get only users from aspnet db.

Claims provider is my default provider.

**Question:** Why can't I get other users ( from AD) when I call GetAllUsers on claims ("i") provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to override a method from your claimsprovider that gets all the users from AD AND from the SQL database

Maybe you could use an active directory membershipprovider?
http://blog.bergdaniel.se/post/Using-the-active-directory-membership-provider-with-EPiServer.aspx

Comment: There is no need for overriding. It was just necessary to add ldap provider to web config and in code write
MembershipProvider membership = Membership.Providers["LdapMembershipProvider"]; Even "FindUsersByEmail" work correctly!

Comment: Ok, glad you found it :)